# Return column heading by matching rows

Tags: excel, vlookup

Here is the sheet which has costs for multiple plan.

[image]

I would like to choose the plan which has minimum cost.

I did a min(cells) to do that but would like to display the selected plan(colhdg) instead of the minimum value.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$E$1,MATCH($F2,$A2:$E2,0))
```

It is assumed that the upper most left of your example is in A1.  If not, adjust accordingly.

To combine the two, the min and the formula above, then:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$E$1,MATCH(MIN($B2:$E2),$A2:$E2,0))
```